# How to Enable Proper Snap Functionability in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, snap

Trying here to install a package via `snapd`, but keeps receiving following output:

`$ sudo snap hello
Warning: /snap/bin was not found in your $PATH. If you've not restarted your
         session since you installed snapd, try doing that. Please see
         https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/9469 for more details.`

When trying to run the application, receives the following:

`$ hello
Command 'hello' is available in '/snap/bin/hello'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
hello: command not found`

May anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin` at the end of proper `.bashrc` file, remembering that the one for root user is different from the users one.

Then `$ source .bashrc`, and `$ hello`.